# Styling road maps with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, visualisation, references

I am trying to design a beautiful map using QGIS. 
There is a similar question here [Seeking QGIS tutorials and web resources?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/qgis-tutorials-and-resources) but I would like to focus on "designing a map using QGIS".

I was looking for some tools, style database or tutorials to guide me.
[How to use label classes, expressions, and annotations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/advanced-labeling-in-qgis) helped me a lot and OSM seems to look great: [1](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap_data_rendered_with_QGIS), [2](http://gis-lab.info/qa/osm-qgis-projects.html). However I need to use my own shapefiles. Also there is [Quantumnik](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/quantumnik/wiki/Home). It could be a great help, however it prints map on another tab and I need it to be on the same with my QGIS project.

I am looking for a way to design a beautiful looking road map using basic QGIS tools, any resources on that?

Comment: But I would rather leave this question more general, not including atributes... For more help in my case then lets focus only on roads. I have 8 shapefiles for roads, each of them for different road sizes. They all have such attributes as Name, number, type and directional. For me only Type and Name is important.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Tomtom data for example, you have an attribute called frc that can be used to classify roads. The following setup will create a GoogleMaps-style roadmap with different styles for different zoom levels.

[image]

I've worked out a solution for Google-like labeling too, this time based on OSM data: http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/guide-to-advanced-labeling-for-osm-roads/

[image]

More related posts:

- ["Advanced Layer Styles in QGIS"](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/advanced-layer-styles-in-qgis/)
- [A guide to GoogleMaps-like maps with OSM in QGIS](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/)

Comment: Thank you! For my case I would also add tip to use scale dependant rendering to add smaller roads only when zoomed in enough and have them pale before they go solid, but I guess it is quite obvious

Answer (score 11):

I have created a blog post on how I did, and just thought to share it here.. So here it is:

http://mikeongis.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/map-design-with-qgis/